# ValueError: Expect the data to StructuredDataInput to have shape (batch_size, num_features), but got input shape [32, 100, 1]

Tags: python

reg.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, verbose=0)

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 reg.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, verbose=0)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/autokeras/analysers/input_analysers.py in check(self)
113                 "(batch_size, num_features), but "
114                 "got input shape {shape}.".format(
--> 115                     input_name=self.get_input_name(), shape=self.shape
116                 )
117             )

ValueError: Expect the data to StructuredDataInput to have shape (batch_size, num_features), but got input shape [32, 100, 1].

I understand that it is because the batch size is 32. But shouldn't the model make a regression taking into account the given shapes?

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just Reshape the data to 2d array. i.e.,
your_data.reshape(32,100)